# Кодировка кириллицы в ascii python

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, кодировка, ascii

Мне нужно закодировать строку с русскими буквами(кириллицей) в ascii.
Пытаюсь сделать это: ‘абв’.encode(‘ascii’)
Получаю ошибку: UnicodeEncodeError: ‘ascii’ codec can’t encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128).
В чем проблема? Как я могу закодировать кириллицу в ascii?
Я использую windows, Visual Studio.

Comment: В ascii нет кириллицы

Comment: В ascii нет кириллицы, вам нужна расширенная кодировка ascii, попробуйте windows-1251.

Comment: Лучше расскажите какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить

Comment: @Alexey Ten Мне нужно закодировать строку с кириллицей и отправить по udp, нужна кодировка ascii

Comment: @tewboat То есть если windows-1251 – это расширенная кодировка ascii? И ее можно использовать вместо ascii?

Comment: @АлександрТрифонов это другая кодировка, частично совпадающая с ascii (процентов на 40% наверное). Можно ли использовать - зависит от того, зачем конкретно вам нужно ascii.

Comment: если так случилось, что можно передать только 7 бит (ну мало чего) и только аскии, тогда нужно кириллицу кодировать в base64. А с той стороны можно будет достать в такой же форме. Если это какой то кастомный протокол, тогда у автором протокола и спрашивайте.

Comment: Не нужна. UDP отлично передаёт все 8 бит, так что какой-нибудь UTF-8 без проблем передаётся.

Comment: @Alexey Ten это я знаю, но на той стороне принимается именно ascii

Comment: Значит та сторона не умеет кириллицу. Либо выясняйте у той стороны как именно к ним надо передавать кириллицу

Answer (score 1):

В ascii нет кирилицы. Используйте другую кодировку. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set